# determine (identify) dc.js chart type

Tags: javascript, dc.js

I'm looking for some solution to determine or identify existing dc.js chart types on the page. I need it to work properly with d3.tip. For different types of charts I use different javascript code.

Answer (score 0):

As answered by Matt Traynham on gitter, there is nothing built-in to do this, but you can add a member  when you create a chart, as long as it has a name that doesn't clash with the chart members

```
var chart = dc.rowChart("#history");
chart.chartType = 'row';
chart.chartType; // "row"
```

PRs welcome!

Answer (score 0):

```
chart.constructor.name
```

This worked for me.